# Handling man in the middle attacks in NServiceBus

Tags: security, nservicebus, man-in-the-middle

Were looking to use NServiceBus to communicate to a DMZ web server from a backend application server and I was looking for guidance to secure against a MITM attack.

How can the message be encrypted (prevent eavesdropping) and hashed (prevent tampering) using either NServiceBus or any other way?

Any help with this would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OOTB way to do this in NSB is to basic [encryption](http://nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/Encryption.aspx) feature.  If you require more than that, I would take a look at [Message Mutators](http://nservicebus.com/MessageMutators.aspx).  These are extension points that allow you to manipulate messages at the application level and the transport level.  It sounds to me like you'd like to get in on the transport level.

Comment: +1 the MessageMutator sample show how to create a compressing mutator, you can easily tweek that to encrypt instead - http://nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/MessageMutatorsSample.aspx